# Как изменить .ToString() в Enum

Tags: c#, .net, строки

Есть Enum

```
   public enum ExerciseCategorysEnum
    {
        None,        
        Like_and_comment,
        Subscribe,
        Register,
        Donate,
    }
```

В нём есть *Like_and_comment*, но мне надо что бы при обращении к ней .ToString() выдавалось *Like and comment*, Я знаю что могу использовать просто после .ToString() .Replace("_", " "), но это долго и не очень практично, а как оверрайтнуть ToString в Enum`e я не знаю, по этому и прошу помощи

Comment: через класс расширения со своим методом. пример тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/479453

Comment: Не делают такое в `enum`. Нужно другое название, вешайте атрибут с нужным названием, делайте метод, который считает это, работайте. Но сам enum должен быть без изменений.

Comment: Не называйте члены enum через `_`, используйте CamelCase

Comment: Спасибо, добавил помогающий класс, который всё это делает

Comment: Можете скинуть про CamelCase?

Comment: Тот костыль который превращает ваш enum в человекочитаемую строку - плохая идея поскольку неизвестно какой язык еще может быть, для локализации используют отдельные свойства у классов, а так же файл json содержащий нужную культуру и локализованный под неё текст, а дальше в коде подключаете какой-нибудь сервис и вызываете нужный метод по ключу из жсон

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, пойду поищу что-то в интернете:>

Comment: есть интерфейс IStringLocalizer, сконфигурируйте его и затем инжектите в конструктор

Comment: Можно повесить атрибут с описанием, и не заниматься ерундой вроде `ToString`, и изменением строки. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3624947

Comment: Это перечисление значит, что чтобы вам ввести еще категорию, придется переписывать код. Не надо хардкодить такое. Храните данные за пределами кода, в конфигах или базе данных.

Comment: Метод `ToString` предназначен для вывода информации в процессе отладки, для разработчика. Не для вывода информации конечному пользователю в UI. Поэтому использовать дополнительный метод - правильное решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В перечисления не хардкодят данные, а у вас это именно данные. В перечисления хардкодят то, что никогда не поменяется. Это делается для того чтобы не пришлось переписывать код в случае внесения изменений в данные.

Поэтому лучше изначально начинать использовать рантайм-структуры данных вместо перечислений.

```
Dictionary<string, string> items = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["None"] = "None",        
    ["LikeAndComment"] = "Like and comment",
    ["Subscribe"] = "Subscribe",
    ["Register"] = "Register",
    ["Donate"] = "Donate"
};
```

Преимущество словаря в том, что вам необязательно хранить его в коде, его можно загрузить например из JSON или базы данных, его можно редактировать прямо в рантайме. При этом не придется пересобирать и релизить новую версию програмного комплекса.

```
Console.WriteLine(items["LikeAndComment"]);
```

```
Like and comment
```

Так же здесь появляется возможность использовать разные языки, например вы сможете загрузить в словарь строки на русском языке, в зависимости от предпочтений пользователя.

Если словарь кажется сложным, а в качестве индексов хочется использовать числа, можно использовать вообще список или массив.

```
string[] items = new string[]
{
    "None",        
    "Like and comment",
    "Subscribe",
    "Register",
    "Donate"
};
```

```
Console.WriteLine(items[1]);
```

```
Like and comment
```

Список так же легко сериализуется и хранится во внешних данных.

Что касается прикручивания кастомных строк к перечислениям, то делается это через атрибуты.

```
public enum ExerciseCategorysEnum
{
    None,
    [EnumMember(Value = "Like and comment")]
    Like_and_comment,
    Subscribe,
    Register,
    Donate,
}

public static class EnumMemberExtensions
{
    public static string GetName<T>(this T member) where T : Enum
    {
        string name = member.ToString();
        return typeof(T).GetField(name)?
            .GetCustomAttribute<EnumMemberAttribute>()?.Value ?? name;
    }
}
```

```
Console.WriteLine(ExerciseCategorysEnum.Like_and_comment.GetName());
```

```
Like and comment
```

Comment: Неплохой способ, но наверное вместо кастомного стоит юзать готовый `DisplayAttribute` из `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`

Comment: @Aarnihauta https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute

Comment: А, вот как, я полностью ответ не читал, думал Вы кастомный сделали

Answer (score 1):

Решил тем, что взял метод с https://stackoverflow.com/a/479453, и переделал под себя

```
public static class ToStringExercise
    {
        public static string ToFriendlyString(this ExerciseCategorysEnum me)
        {
            return me.ToString().Replace("_", "");
        }
    }
```